# Scala: can't write setter without getter?

Tags: scala

This works:

```
class ButtonCountObserver {
  private var cnt = 0  // private field
  def count = cnt      // reader method
  def count_=(newCount: Int) = cnt = newCount  // writer method
 // ...
}

val b = new ButtonCountObserver 
b.count = 0
```

But this doesn't

```
class ButtonCountObserver {
  private var cnt = 0  // private field
  def count_=(newCount: Int) = cnt = newCount  // writer method
 // ...
}

val b = new ButtonCountObserver 
b.count = 0
```

I get: `error: value count is not a member of ButtonCountObserver`

Is it possible to create a setter (with the syntactic sugar) without a getter?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The spec requires that both a setter and getter are defined to be able to use the syntactic sugar for calling the setter:

> The interpretation of an assignment to
>   a simple variable x = e depends on the
>   definition of x. If x denotes a
>   mutable variable, then the assignment
>   changes the current value of x to be
>   the result of evaluating the
>   expression e. The type of e is
>   expected to conform to the type of x.
>   **If x is a parameterless function
>   defined in some template, and the same
>   template contains a setter function
>   x_= as member, then the assignment x =
>   e is interpreted as the invocation
>   x_=(e ) of that setter function.**
>   Analogously, an assignment f .x = e to
>   a parameterless function x is
>   interpreted as the invocation f .x_=(e
>   ). An assignment f (args) = e with a
>   function application to the left of
>   the ‘=’ operator is interpreted as f
>   .update(args, e ), i.e. the invocation
>   of an update function defined by f .

Furthermore, the getter must be visible in order to use the setter. I'm not sure if this is specified

### Getter not visible #1

```
// error: method x cannot be accessed in x.Test
object x {
  class Test { 
    private[this] var x0: Int = 0
    private[Test] def x = x0
    def x_=(a: Int) = x0 = a 
  }
  val t = new Test
  t.x = 1
}
```

### Getter not visible #2

```
//<console>:11: error: type mismatch; found   : x.Test required: ?{val x: ?}
object x {
  class Test { 
    private[this] var x0: Int = 0
    private[this] def x = x0
    def x_=(a: Int) = x0 = a 
  }
  val t = new Test
  t.x = 1
}
```

### Getter visible

```
object x {
  class Test { 
    private[this] var x0: Int = 0
    private[x] def x = x0
    def x_=(a: Int) = x0 = a 
  }
  val t = new Test
  t.x = 1
}
```

Comment: The "Getter Visible" example does not work in repl.  <console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : x.type (with underlying type object x)
 required: ?{val x: ?}

Answer (score 0):

As retronym pointed out, there must be a getter present. As a workaround however (if you don't want to provide a getter), you can make the getter return `Unit`

```
object x {
  class Test { 
    private[this] var x0: Int = 0
    def x: Unit = ()
    def x_=(a: Int) = x0 = a 
  }
  val t = new Test
  t.x = 1
}
```

Don't think that that is considered good style (!), but it works.