# Why am I getting "is not a member" here?

Tags: scala, methods

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Zip Code Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471/zip-code-database)
>   [Scala: can't write setter without getter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447132/scala-cant-write-setter-without-getter)

```
class Person {
 def age_= (val value:Int) {  }
}
object Main { 
  def main( args : Array[String] ) { 
    val s = new Person()
    s.age = 10
  }
}
```

I thought Scala gave special treatment to `bla_=` by allowing it to be used as `foo.bar = baz`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447132/scala-cant-write-setter-without-getter