# Why doesn't Scala keep track of anonymous types?

Tags: scala, types, type-inference

In particular, this minimal example:

```
trait A[T1, T2] {
  def convert(t1: T1): T2
  def reverse(t2: T2): T1
}

class B extends A[Int, Double]  {
  def convert(i: Int): Double = i.toDouble
  def reverse(i: Double): Int = i.toInt
}

class C extends A[Int, Float] {
  def convert(i: Int): Float = i.toFloat
  def reverse(i: Float): Int = i.toInt
}

val bOrC: A[Int, _] = if (System.nanoTime % 2 == 0) {
  new B
} else {
  new C
}

bOrC.convert(7)
bOrC.reverse(bOrC.convert(7))
```

Will fail on the last line:

```
scala> bOrC.reverse(bOrC.convert(7))
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (some other)_$1(in value bOrC)
 required: _$1(in value bOrC)
              bOrC.reverse(bOrC.convert(7))
```

It seems that the type of `_$1` is the same in both the return type and the argument - it's `bOrC`'s `T2` type, whatever it may be. Local type inference shouldn't be a problem here. Why can't I do this?

Is there a workaround that isn't as ugly as the following?

```
trait A[T1, T2] {
  def convert(t1: T1): T2
  def reverse(t2: X): T1
  type X = T2
}
// ... rest as before
bOrC.reverse(bOrC.convert(7).asInstanceOf[bOrC.X])
```

**Edit**: looks like if you *tell* Scala it's the same type, everything is handled. This gets rid of the silly `type X`:

```
def thereAndBack[T2](a: A[Int, T2], b: Int) = a.reverse(a.convert(b))
thereAndBack(bOrC)
```

Comment: The underscore in this context isn't an "anonymous type", it's an _existential type_--which means you're telling the compiler you _don't care_ what the type is, so the compiler will happily treat it as such.

Comment: There a dissonance between your requirement of remembering the type and the usage of existential type, which does exactly the opposite of what you want.

Comment: @m-z OK, yes, I don't care what type it is. But it is the same type being returned and used, whatever it is. Something seems missing there.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'd be happy to accept your answer, if you can show me why my question is ill-posed.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it is a type forSome { type X }. It's that not we don't care about the type (and can forget it), it's that we don't care to name it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can treat `A` as a typeclass and only have one of `B` / `C` available implicitly?

```
def convert[T1, T2](x: T1)(implicit a: A[T1, T2]): T2 = {
  a.convert(x)
}

def reverse[T1, T2](x: T2)(implicit a: A[T1, T2]): T1 = {
  a.reverse(x)
}

implicit val b = new B
// or implicit val c = new C

convert(7)
reverse(convert(7))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think this solution won't work. You're forcing a single code path to have one behavior, but this solution won't work if it's dependent on some runtime-determined value (such as `System.nanoTime` in my example).

Also, it's not quite answering the _why_ question.

Comment: I think why questions are disallowed; only how questions, IIUC.

Comment: @som-snytt That's a change from several questions I've asked before, and it hasn't been pointed out to me yet. Are you referencing something on the FAQ?

Comment: @VF1 "why" usually invites opinions instead of solving a specific problem. here's a sample where I just tried to answer it anyway, and of course one winds up arguing in circles. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134978/why-cant-you-create-a-setter-without-getter-in-scala/39135701#39135701

Comment: @som-snytt I agree that it is an invitation for opinions in general, but in this case, I think "why" can be a specific answer. E.g., the compiler doesn't have support for this / there's some crazy programming language theory that justifies this behavior / etc. would answer "why" here to satisfaction.